# Listening for Multiple Events on Multiple Objects AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, function, event-listener

I currently have an over, out and click event for 8 different objects. The over and out events are identical for each (tween expands object and then shrinks it back for the out state).

I have previously asked for an easy way to declare those events, and now I was looking for an easier way to handle them.

Here's my code:

```
//-----------GARAGE
function growGarage(e:MouseEvent):void{
     scaleTweenX = new Tween(map_garage, "scaleX", Elastic.easeOut, 0.648, 1, 0.5, true);
     scaleTweenY = new Tween(map_garage, "scaleY", Elastic.easeOut, 0.648, 1, 0.5, true);
}
function shrinkGarage(e:MouseEvent):void{
     scaleTweenX = new Tween(map_garage, "scaleX", Elastic.easeOut, 1, 0.648, 0.5, true);
     scaleTweenY = new Tween(map_garage, "scaleY", Elastic.easeOut, 1, 0.648, 0.5, true);
}
function garageClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
     trace("clicked");
}
//-----------B&B
function growBandb(e:MouseEvent):void{
     scaleTweenX = new Tween(map_bandb, "scaleX", Elastic.easeOut, 0.648, 1, 0.5, true);
     scaleTweenY = new Tween(map_bandb, "scaleY", Elastic.easeOut, 0.648, 1, 0.5, true);
}
function shrinkBandb(e:MouseEvent):void{
     scaleTweenX = new Tween(map_bandb, "scaleX", Elastic.easeOut, 1, 0.648, 0.5, true);
     scaleTweenY = new Tween(map_bandb, "scaleY", Elastic.easeOut, 1, 0.648, 0.5, true);
}
function bandbClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
     trace("clicked");
}
//-----------FACTORY
function growFactory(e:MouseEvent):void{
     scaleTweenX = new Tween(map_factory, "scaleX", Elastic.easeOut, 0.648, 1, 0.5, true);
     scaleTweenY = new Tween(map_factory, "scaleY", Elastic.easeOut, 0.648, 1, 0.5, true);
}
function shrinkFactory(e:MouseEvent):void{
     scaleTweenX = new Tween(map_factory, "scaleX", Elastic.easeOut, 1, 0.648, 0.5, true);
     scaleTweenY = new Tween(map_factory, "scaleY", Elastic.easeOut, 1, 0.648, 0.5, true);
}
function factoryClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
     trace("clicked");
}
//-----------SCHOOL
function growSchool(e:MouseEvent):void{
     scaleTweenX = new Tween(map_school, "scaleX", Elastic.easeOut, 0.648, 1, 0.5, true);
     scaleTweenY = new Tween(map_school, "scaleY", Elastic.easeOut, 0.648, 1, 0.5, true);
}
function shrinkSchool(e:MouseEvent):void{
     scaleTweenX = new Tween(map_school, "scaleX", Elastic.easeOut, 1, 0.648, 0.5, true);
     scaleTweenY = new Tween(map_school, "scaleY", Elastic.easeOut, 1, 0.648, 0.5, true);
}
function schoolClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
     trace("clicked");
}
```

I've tried using a single function and then using "this" as the object of the tween but that expanded the entire stage.

Is there a way to condense this code?

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single handler, instead of using `this`, use `e.currentTarget`.  (When `e` is your incoming event)